# Calculating AWS S3 etag value for a local file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Is there anyway to calculate etag value of a local file before uploading it to S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the file in chunks of bytes
2. Calculate the `MD5 checksum` for each chunk and store it for later use
3. Calculate the `md5 hexdigest` of the concatenated checksums

[Check this](https://teppen.io/2018/10/23/aws_s3_verify_etags/#calculating-an-s3-etag-using-python) for Calculating the `S3 ETag` for a local file in `Python`

Comment: Note that the linked code does not work for objects that are dropped through an sftp. It also runs the expensive hashing function multiple parts for the possibilities. Might as well avoid using ETag and save the hash digest as a file meta. In many cases it's not possible.